# Approach to interpretation when continuous predictors are components of multiple (two-way) interactions?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

I have a multiple regression model in which several of the continuous predictor variables participate in more than one two-way interaction. Needless to say, this complicates their interpretation. The interactions all contribute to the model's best fit to the data and make sense given our knowledge of the system being investigated, but describing them in more detail than just generalized qualitative terms is going to be difficult. I have not found a discussion of this situation in books or online. I welcome any guidance or recommendations of discussions in textbooks and articles on how to best approach the task of understanding/interpreting the relationships of the response variable to the predictors given these interactions. Thanks.